# Facebook Insights for Multi-tenant Applications

Tags: facebook, multi-tenant, facebook-insights

We have a multi-tenant application which posts news stories on behalf of many different customers to a website that we own.  Those stories are then shared in Facebook by visitors to the website.  We would like to be able to share insights data with our customers for just their stories.  However, it appears that Facebook only provides aggregate insights data at the domain level.  So, we're trying to figure out how best to accomplish this goal.

One idea we had was to subdivide the website which our news stories are posted to by client, giving each client a subdomain, i.e., client-a.website.com, client-b.website.com, ... etc. and then setup a Facebook application for each client.  According to [Facebook's documentation](http://www.facebook.com/help/157134244354040/), this approach should work.  However, we have several hundred clients and I'm not sure A) if setting up that many Facebook applications is even feasible and B) if that's a good idea even if it is feasible; seems wrought with possible maintenance problems.

Another idea we had was to somehow utilize the Open Graph to create objects which relate to each of our customers. I believe you can get aggregate Insights data by open graph object, though, I'm not sure if that's object type or object *instance*, e.g., Recipe (Type) vs. Grandma's Mac+Cheese (Instance).

Anyways, I'm curious to know if anyone else out there has dealt with this before and the approaches that you may have taken (good or bad).

Comment: I realized that it is not necessary to create a Facebook Application for each sub-domain, i.e., client-a.website.com, client-b.website.com, ... etc.  Instead we can add all of our subdomains to our single Facebook Application (hopefully there is no limit as we have hundreds of clients).

Comment: how did you end up getting the insights for OpenGraph objects ?